# Java JButton ActiveBackground

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How do I set the active background color of a button in swing, java?
Active background color is the color of the background of the button while it is being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo of JButton **Background color changed** while **moving the mouse on** and **click the button:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JButtonBGColorDemo {

    class ColorTestButton extends JButton {

        private Color hoverBackgroundColor;
        private Color pressedBackgroundColor;

        public ColorTestButton() {
            this(null);
        }

        public ColorTestButton(String text) {
            super(text);
            super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (getModel().isPressed()) {
                g.setColor(pressedBackgroundColor);
            } else if (getModel().isRollover()) {
                g.setColor(hoverBackgroundColor);
            } else {
                g.setColor(getBackground());
            }
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentAreaFilled(boolean b) {
        }

        public Color getHoverBackgroundColor() {
            return hoverBackgroundColor;
        }

        public void setHoverBackgroundColor(Color hoverBackgroundColor) {
            this.hoverBackgroundColor = hoverBackgroundColor;
        }

        public Color getPressedBackgroundColor() {
            return pressedBackgroundColor;
        }

        public void setPressedBackgroundColor(Color pressedBackgroundColor) {
            this.pressedBackgroundColor = pressedBackgroundColor;
        }
    }

    protected void createUIDesign() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final ColorTestButton btn = new ColorTestButton("Color Test Button");
        btn.setForeground(new Color(0, 135, 200).brighter());
        btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        btn.setBorder(null);
        btn.setBackground(new Color(3, 59, 90));
        btn.setHoverBackgroundColor(new Color(3, 59, 90).brighter());
        btn.setPressedBackgroundColor(Color.PINK);
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JButtonBGColorDemo().createUIDesign();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for all your buttons you might be able to change the default using the LAF:

```
UIManager.put("Button.select", Color.RED);
```

The above code should be executed BEFORE you create your components.